# Web site not accessible when "www" is not used

Tags: apache, web

I have a web domain registered and a hosting space.

When I access my website with `www` (for ex. `www.example.com`) it shows expected content. However when I try to access it without `www` (for ex. `example.com`) it shows site under construction page. This site under construction page is provided by web hosting provider and is html file.

What changes are required for accessing site both ways?

Comment: I Think you should setup DNS to *.example.com. Add A record on your hosting DNS manager

Comment: Which hosting site are you using?

Comment: Does hosting site matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating `A record` and `CNAME record` usually is the solution - but on your authoritative DNS.

You will want to put A and/or CNAME records into master DNS, not secondary DNS. There are two approaches to DNS which are:

1. authoritative DNS (master DNS)
2. local DNS (usually resides on your host machine/router) (secondary DNS)

Indeed - it is not simple as it may seemed. To have your own working authoriative DNS, you need 2 host machines physcially connected to two different separated ip addresses (eth0 physical connect - not virtually bridged).  Since this is so complicated and time-consuming implemention, it is typical to outsource master DNS to a DNS provider (and is a common practice among many of us).

I have 4 servers on my one ip, and my local DNS are being managed in between my router and 4 host machines and it works great on local network ONLY.  Since I wanted the local network to be hooked to my domain, I outsourced my master DNS to http://dnsimple.com (there are other DNS provider competitors), so it'd manage my domain directly.  This therefore functions as an authoritative DNS, known as master DNS.

The issue you are trying to fix should be focused toward master DNS, not secondary DNS (local network) as it'd not work.  If you got your domain via a registrar company or a web-hosting company, you should be able to find the setting/management on your account with the company (for example, C-Panel)...not DNS on your local network.

EDITED:  This is a tool that I always use and is a great benefit in tackling down DNS / Domain issues.  I dont know what I'd have done without it.  http://www.dnsstuff.com/tools

Answer (score 3):

setup an A-record for the domain name without the 'www' prefix pointing to the IP address of
the  web-server, and setup a CNAME-record for the domain name with the 'www' prefix pointing 
to  the web-server IP.

Comment: DNS changes may take a while (up to 6 or even 24 hours) to propagate.

Answer (score 3):

use a CNAME record for "www" to point it to the base name. Use an A record for the base name.

But I find it easier (and it's ever so slightly faster for users) to simply use an A record for both the base name and www.